Does CORS completely eliminate CSRF attack for a MERN stack app that uses session-based auth?
My current setup: I have backend & frontend hosted on completely different domains. From backend I'm sending back an httpOnly cookie that contains session id. Frontend checks login status by hitting /user/status.
(As an aside, I know that session-based auth is not common in MERN stack apps, where JWT is preferred. I'm assuming my approach violates REST principles a bit. But for my use case, sessions are way more comfortable than fighting with limitations and edge cases of JWT)
I have CORS properly setup. My question is, having CORS set up and limiting incoming request content type to only application/json, is my website prone to CSRF attack at all? Since backend and frontend are on completely different domains, I have to set sameSite=None for the cookie to be sent, but to my understanding, it's not an issue since CORS will block any malicious web requests from 3rd party websites.
Again, is it safe to assume that CORS completely eliminates CSRF attack possibility for my type of setup?

No. CORS's purpose is not to strengthen, but to relax security in the browser. CORS is not a defence, and definitely not a defence against CSRF. If you're app is safe from CSRF, it's most definitely not on account of CORS being activated.

@jub0bs can you elaborate? In what ways is my app still vulnerable given CORS prevents 3rd party requests (only allowing my frontend)?

CORS does not prevent anything. The SOP does, but only browsers implement it. CORS is a mechanism for relaxing the SOP; as such, it cannot be a defence.

If you rely on cookie-based authentication and have no defence against CSRF, you're in trouble, regardless of whether you've activated CORS.

@jub0bs "you're in trouble" - that's what I asked you to elaborate. In what ways can CSRF happen given my setup?

I'd have to see the full code of or have access to the server to give a definite answer. But check out https://jub0bs.com/posts/2022-02-08-cve-2022-21703-writeup/#bypassing-content-type-validation-and-avoiding-cors-preflight. IIUIC, your setup is close enough to Grafana's, at least at the time.

I'm not sure what you mean by "limiting incoming request content type to only application/json", but if you rely on this as a defence against CSRF, keep in mind that it's error-prone.
